# Multithreaded file digest

Tags: java, multithreading, hash, digest, fork-join

I'm doing some hobby apps, and I need to calculate the hash of a partition and my current code looks the following:

```
public class DiskHandler {
File diskRoot;

public DiskHandler() {
    diskRoot = new File("\\\\.\\C:");
}

public String calculateSHA1() {
    System.out.println("sha1 hash started");
    try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(diskRoot)) {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");

        byte[] bytesBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead = -1;

        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(bytesBuffer)) != -1) {
            digest.update(bytesBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        byte[] hashedBytes = digest.digest();

        return convertByteArrayToHexString(hashedBytes);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}

private static String convertByteArrayToHexString(byte[] arrayBytes) {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayBytes.length; i++) {
        stringBuffer.append(Integer.toString((arrayBytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
    }
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}

}
```

The issue with this is that I have a CPU bottleneck. It uses one CPU core and I have an SSD and the read speed is currently 25MB/s.

Is there a way to get parallel hashing like using the `ForkJoin` framework or something else?

Comment: You can't compute a single digest in parallel. Each round has to be computed sequentially. If you are computing a digest for each individual file, that could be parallelized.

Answer (score 0):

The `ForkJoin` framework is suitable for compute bound tasks more than `IO-Bound` tasks.

Basically, you have two problems, one is IO (reading the file), and the other is compute (calculating the hash).

You could use an [AsynchronousFileChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html), read a chunk of the file, and calculate the hash of the partition you read in a different thread once the partition is read.

But as [@erickson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35807641/multithreaded-file-digest/35807773?noredirect=1#comment59285129_35807773) pointed out in his comment, you need to profile to check if this is gonna buy you anything. Remember something, the point is not making the two cores hot, it is making the program faster.

Comment: It would be interesting to profile this to see whether reading in one thread and computing in another would actually be faster. I doubt it would be in this case, but it's hard to guess.

Comment: @erickson absolutely, measurement is required. But I think, it would pay off if the file is big.

Comment: the file is 230gb for example, its a whole disk hash.
i increased the buffer consistently to 64mb as is sequential read and a 230gb partition, it performs faster, but the problem is cpu bottleneck, as i said, im using a 840 evo ssd as source, ios are not the problem here

Comment: @user3707555 have you tried the idea I mentioned? Let us know if you do

Comment: i tweaked the buffer size and im getting better results 180mb/s reported with windows task manager, but activity time is 66%, i'll try splitting read and proccess in differents threads and ill post the results